# Conditional border for links/buttons in navbar

Tags: html, css

On my web site I have a navigation bar (with pseudo-buttons made from links). The whole navigation bar has a bottom-border, to separate the menu from the content below.

Now, using HTML and CSS I want to achieve a similar effect as here on stackoverflow, in the sub menu, as can be seen here:

[image]

The whole navbar has a bottom-border, except for the selected menu item. This looks like a register card, or similar.

My current menu CSS looks like this:

```
.nav-main {
    clear: both;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
.nav-main-link {
    color: #666 !important;
    background: rgba(230, 236, 182, .99);
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.nav-main-link:hover,
.nav-main-selected {
    background: #738925;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And the HTML part:

```
<div class="nav-main">
    <ul class="nav-main-list">
        <li class="nav-main-item nav-main-test1">
            <a href="../index.php/test1" class="nav-main-link nav-main-selected">Test 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-main-item nav-main-test2">
            <a href="../index.php/test2" class="nav-main-link">Test 2</a>
        </li>
    <div class="nav-main-clear">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any easy way in HTML+CSS to achieving the described behaviour?

PS: Sorry for the title of this question, but I am not sure how to name it better :)

Comment: Have you analysed Stackoverflow's implementation?

Comment: Could we see your html as well?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Yes sure, I have played around with it for a bit. But unfortunately I am not really an CSS expert, so I was not able to achieve exactly the same behaviour (only to some extend).

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot: I have added the HTML section used on my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's not that very complicated

I suppose you're using unordered list of items with links like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="...">Link 1</a>
    ...
</ul>
```

In this case you should set style to your `UL` to have bottom border. That will display across the whole line.

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Now you have to set individual `LI`'s style. Especially the selected one's. If you move it one pixel (or as much as border is thick) lower and either set its bottom border to background color or provide it a backrgound color, it will overlay `UL` bottom border. Then also set it other borders so it displays as a tab.

```
li.selected {
    display: inline-block; /* to flow them horizontally */
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/litera/rgDBH/).

Answer (score 0):

my attempt:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <ul>
            <li>Page 1</li>
            <li id="checked">Selected Page</li>
            <li>Page 2</li>
            <li>Page 3</li>
            <li>Page 4</li>
            <li>Page 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.header ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #eeeeee;
}
.header li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
#checked{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #eeeeee;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;  
}
```

fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dBK4C/1/)